# How to get the source of the .load() url

Tags: jquery

Once I do `$("#obj").load(url)` is there a way to get the loaded url from `#obj` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That code will just load the contents of `#obj` in the DOM using the results of a call to `url`. jQuery will not store the url anywhere. But you can manually store the data and attach it to the dom object using `data()`. Like this:

```
$("#obj").load(url).data('url', url);
```

You can then later retrieve the url like this:

```
var url = $("#obj").data('url');
```

See http://api.jquery.com/data/ for details.

Comment: I would like to retrieve the content of the jquery .load() function. I did not know how to get it. I used your example, and it worked like a charm. However, I wonder, there is no a more elegant solution to get the loaded content of the load function? e.g. var load_content = .load() ....retrieve( load_content)? or '.data(load(url content ) ) '? Thanks @Ben Lee

Comment: I'm not sure I follow your question completely...`load` already retrieves the content (that's what it _does_) and injects into the element. To later analyze the contents, you can just look at the contents of the element (using `.html()`, `.text()`, or `.contents()` depending on the form of the content you want)

Comment: Sorry Ben for not explaining clearly: The same url is repeated 3 times. This can be avoided? `$(document).ready(function(){  $("
           $("#idR_Code_PSPP").click(function(){
          $("#mainbody").load("R_Code_PSPP.html #st_en").data('url_idR_Code_PSPP', "R_Code_PSPP.html#st_en")
               var url_idR_Code_PSPP = url  `

Comment: *Sorry for misunderstanding. I mean: "content = the url". The url is repeated three times: in .load(), in data(), and in var url = data(url).... So this repeat process  can be avoided e.g.  _var load_content = .load()_ in order to retrieve _the url, not the content_. :)

Comment: There's no more elegant way that I know of.

Answer (score 0):

Here it is an actual example, that It uses Language selection, together with loading content using Jquery syntax:

In the body:

```
<a href="index.html"    class="topnav_estatistics">ESTATISTICS </a>
<a id="idStatistics"     href ="#Statistics"      > <span lang="en">Statistics      </span>     <span lang="gr">Στατιστική      </span>   </a>
<a id="idR_Code_PSPP"    href ="#R_Code_PSPP"     > <span lang="en">R Code / PSPP   </span>     <span lang="gr"> R Code / PSPP  </span>   </a>
<a id="idStat_Article"   href ="#Stat_Article"    > <span lang="en">Stat Articles   </span>     <span lang="gr"> Άρθρα          </span>   </a>   
<a id="idPlanets_Health" href ="#Planets_Health"  > <span lang="en">Planet's Health </span>     <span lang="gr"> Περιβάλλον     </span>   </a>    
<a id="idServices"       href ="#Services"        > <span lang="en">Services        </span>     <span lang="gr"> Υπηρεσίες      </span>   </a>  

        <!--- The Language options  --->
        <select id="lang_switch" class="lang_switch">
           <option value="en">En </option>
           <option value="gr">Gr </option>
        </select>
```

The div section where external html pages div-specific content is loaded.

```
<div id="mainbody" class="main_body"> </div>
<div id="mainbody_2" class="main_body"> </div>

<div id="mainbody_3" class="main_body"> </div>
```

The language selection together with the Jquery document load of external html div-specific content on specific div section of the current page.

```
<script>
    // stackoverflow: 49637061  &  11134701 
$('[lang="en"]').show();
$('[lang="gr"]').hide();
          $(document).ready(function(){
           $("#idR_Code_PSPP").click(function(){
             $("#mainbody").load("R_Code_PSPP.html #st_en").data('url_idR_Code_PSPP', "R_Code_PSPP.html#st_en")
             $("#left_link_index").load("R_Code_PSPP.html #left_links_en")
              var url_idR_Code_PSPP = window.location.protocol+"//"+window.location.hostname+":"+ window.location.port+"/"+ $("#mainbody").data('url_idR_Code_PSPP');
             $("#mainbody_2").html(url_idR_Code_PSPP)
            });   
           $("#idStatistics").click(function(){
            $("#mainbody").load("Statistics.html #st_en").data('url_idStatistics', "Statistics.html#st_en"); 
            $("#left_link_index").load("Statistics.html #left_links_en")
              var url_idStatistics = window.location.protocol+"//"+window.location.hostname+":"+ window.location.port+"/"+$("#mainbody").data('url_idStatistics');
              $("#mainbody_2").html(url_idStatistics)
          }); 
           $("#idStat_Article").click(function(){
             $("#mainbody").load("Stat_Article.html #st_en"  ).data('url_idStat_Article', "Stat_Article.html#st_en");
               var url_idStat_Article = window.location.protocol+"//"+window.location.hostname+":"+ window.location.port+"/"+$("#mainbody").data('url_idStat_Article');
              $("#mainbody_2").html(url_idStat_Article)
          });
           $("#idPlanets_Health").click(function(){
             $("#mainbody").load("Planets_Health.html #st_en").data('url_idPlanets_Health', "Planets_Health.html#st_en");
               var url_idPlanets_Health = window.location.protocol+"//"+window.location.hostname+":"+ window.location.port+"/"+$("#mainbody").data('url_idPlanets_Health'); 
              $("#mainbody_2").html(url_idPlanets_Health)
          }); 
           $("#idServices").click(function(){
             $("#mainbody").load("Services.html #st_en").data('url_idServices', "Services.html#st_en");
             $("#left_link_index").load("Services.html #left_links_en"); 
               var url_idServices = window.location.protocol+"//"+window.location.hostname+":"+ window.location.port+"/"+$("#mainbody").data('url_idServices'); 
              $("#mainbody_2").html(url_idServices)
          }); 
          $(document).on('click', '#id_bio_history_en', function(){
            $("#mainbody").load("Services.html #bio_history_en").data('url_bio_history_en', "Services.html#bio_history_en");
               var url_bio_history_en = window.location.protocol+"//"+window.location.hostname+":"+ window.location.port+"/"+$("#mainbody").data('url_bio_history_en'); 
            $("#mainbody_2").html(url_bio_history_en)
          }); 
          $(document).on('click', '#id_info_en', function(){
            $("#mainbody").load("Services.html #info_en").data('url_info_en', "Services.html#info_en");
               var url_info_en = window.location.protocol+"//"+window.location.hostname+":"+ window.location.port+"/"+$("#mainbody").data('url_info_en'); 
            $("#mainbody_2").html(url_info_en)
          }); 
          }); 

$('#lang_switch').change(function () {
  var lang = $(this).val();
  switch (lang) {
    case 'gr':
      $('[lang]').hide();
      $('[lang="gr"]').show();
         $(document).ready(function(){
           $("#idR_Code_PSPP").click(function(){
             $("#mainbody").load("R_Code_PSPP.html #st_gr").data('url_idR_Code_PSPP', "R_Code_PSPP.html#st_gr"); 
             $("#left_link_index").load("R_Code_PSPP.html #left_links_gr" )
              var url_idR_Code_PSPP = window.location.protocol+"//"+window.location.hostname+":"+ window.location.port+"/"+$("#mainbody").data('url_idR_Code_PSPP');
             $("#mainbody_2").html(url_idR_Code_PSPP)
          });         
           $("#idStatistics").click(function(){
            $("#mainbody").load("Statistics.html #st_gr").data('url_idStatistics', "Statistics.html#st_gr"); 
            $("#left_link_index").load("Statistics.html #left_links_gr")
              var url_idStatistics = window.location.protocol+"//"+window.location.hostname+":"+ window.location.port+"/"+$("#mainbody").data('url_idStatistics');
            $("#mainbody_2").html(url_idStatistics)
          }); 
           $("#idStat_Article").click(function(){
             $("#mainbody").load("Stat_Article.html #st_gr"  ).data('url_idStat_Article', "Stat_Article.html#st_gr");
               var url_idStat_Article = window.location.protocol+"//"+window.location.hostname+":"+ window.location.port+"/"+$("#mainbody").data('url_idStat_Article');
             $("#mainbody_2").html(url_idStat_Article)
          });
           $("#idPlanets_Health").click(function(){
             $("#mainbody").load("Planets_Health.html #st_gr").data('url_idPlanets_Health', "Planets_Health.html#st_gr");
               var url_idPlanets_Health = window.location.protocol+"//"+window.location.hostname+":"+ window.location.port+"/"+$("#mainbody").data('url_idPlanets_Health'); 
             $("#mainbody_2").html(url_idPlanets_Health)
          }); 
           $("#idServices").click(function(){
             $("#mainbody").load("Services.html #st_gr").data('url_idServices', "Services.html#st_gr");
             $("#left_link_index").load("Services.html #left_links_gr"); 
               var url_idServices = window.location.protocol+"//"+window.location.hostname+":"+ window.location.port+"/"+$("#mainbody").data('url_idServices'); 
              $("#mainbody_2").html(url_idServices)
          }); 
          $(document).on('click', '#id_bio_history_gr', function(){
            $("#mainbody").load("Services.html #bio_history_gr").data('url_bio_history_gr', "Services.html#bio_history_gr");
               var url_bio_history_gr = window.location.protocol+"//"+window.location.hostname+":"+ window.location.port+"/"+ $("#mainbody").data('url_bio_history_gr'); 
             $("#mainbody_2").html(url_bio_history_gr)
          }); 
          $(document).on('click', '#id_info_gr', function(){
            $("#mainbody").load("Services.html #info_gr").data('url_info_gr', "Services.html#info_gr");
               var url_info_gr = window.location.protocol+"//"+window.location.hostname+":"+ window.location.port+"/"+$("#mainbody").data('url_info_gr'); 
            $("#mainbody_2").html(url_info_gr)
          });         
          }); 
      break;
      case 'en':
      $('[lang]').hide();
      $('[lang="en"]').show();
         $(document).ready(function(){
           $("#idR_Code_PSPP").click(function(){
             $("#mainbody").load("R_Code_PSPP.html #st_en").data('url_idR_Code_PSPP', "R_Code_PSPP.html#st_en"); 
             $("#left_link_index").load("R_Code_PSPP.html #left_links_en")
              var url_idR_Code_PSPP = window.location.protocol+"//"+window.location.hostname+":"+ window.location.port+"/"+$("#mainbody").data('url_idR_Code_PSPP');
             $("#mainbody_2").html(url_idR_Code_PSPP)
          });         
           $("#idStatistics").click(function(){
            $("#mainbody").load("Statistics.html #st_en").data('url_idStatistics', "Statistics.html#st_en"); 
            $("#left_link_index").load("Statistics.html #left_links_en")
              var url_idStatistics = window.location.protocol+"//"+window.location.hostname+":"+ window.location.port+"/"+$("#mainbody").data('url_idStatistics');
             $("#mainbody_2").html(url_idStatistics)
          }); 
           $("#idStat_Article").click(function(){
             $("#mainbody").load("Stat_Article.html #st_en"  ).data('url_idStat_Article', "Stat_Article.html#st_en");
               var url_idStat_Article = window.location.protocol+"//"+window.location.hostname+":"+ window.location.port+"/"+$("#mainbody").data('url_idStat_Article');
              $("#mainbody_2").html(url_idStat_Article)
          });
           $("#idPlanets_Health").click(function(){
             $("#mainbody").load("Planets_Health.html #st_en").data('url_idPlanets_Health', "Planets_Health.html#st_en");
               var url_idPlanets_Health = window.location.protocol+"//"+window.location.hostname+":"+ window.location.port+"/"+$("#mainbody").data('url_idPlanets_Health'); 
             $("#mainbody_2").html(url_idPlanets_Health)
          }); 
           $("#idServices").click(function(){
             $("#mainbody").load("Services.html #st_en").data('url_idServices', "Services.html#st_en");
             $("#left_link_index").load("Services.html #left_links_en"); 
               var url_idServices = window.location.protocol+"//"+window.location.hostname+":"+ window.location.port+"/"+$("#mainbody").data('url_idServices'); 
              $("#mainbody_2").html(url_idServices)
          }); 
          $(document).on('click', '#id_bio_history_en', function(){
            $("#mainbody").load("Services.html #bio_history_en").data('url_bio_history_en', "Services.html#bio_history_en");
               var url_bio_history_en = window.location.protocol+"//"+window.location.hostname+":"+ window.location.port+"/"+$("#mainbody").data('url_bio_history_en'); 
            $("#mainbody_2").html(url_bio_history_en)
          }); 
          $(document).on('click', '#id_info_en', function(){
            $("#mainbody").load("Services.html #info_en").data('url_info_en', "Services.html#info_en");
               var url_info_en = window.location.protocol+"//"+window.location.hostname+":"+ window.location.port+"/"+$("#mainbody").data('url_info_en'); 
            $("#mainbody_2").html(url_info_en)
          });       
          }); 
      break;
  };
});
</script>
```

The External HTML file must have a div section named e.g.

```
 <div id="info_gr"  class="info_services" >  and/or
 <div id="info_en"  class="info_services" >  or 
 <div id="bio_history_en"  class="biohistory" > and/or
 <div id="bio_history_gr"  class="biohistory" >
```

The script goes exactly before the end, specifically exactly before `"</html>".`